# system.net.webexception C# Vista

Tags: c#, windows-vista, webclient

I have object of type WebClient which successfully connects to web server.  But when I run this code under Vista I get system.net.webexception socket error.

Comment: Post a code the throw exception.

Comment: We need the error to say anything about this...

Comment: Exceptions are naturally thrown if the server returns certain HTTP error codes, even if the connection is successfully established. For instance, you might connect to the server OK but get a 404, which will generate an exception. Provide more info and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a bit bewildered by my other program that used sockets directly (port scanner) that worked under XP and failed to work under Win7.  I thought that might be the case in this current app, but since I used WebClient - high level class - bewilderment was justified)
The problem solved by adding modifying scope in excepion's for my firefall.
Thanx for your time.